# California length, source, and mouth of rivers

Tags: rivers

How can I find out / where can I find the length, "source" (beginning point), "mouth" (ending point) of the *California* portion of rivers?

For example, it's easy to find the length, source, and mouth of the Colorado River, which runs partly through California, but I'm just interested in the California part.

True, I can, through somewhat meticulous research, find the California beginning and ending of the Colorado River on a map, but where can I find the length?

"Googling" provides a plethora of info about the river as a whole, but no so much about just the California portion...

I have the same question for the Klamath (partly in Oregon) and Amargosa (partly in Nevada) rivers.

Comment: Generally speaking, the Colorado River forms the border between California and Arizona. But searching for that I haven't been able to find anything relevant about the length of that border either (I even consulted the 1960s agreement between the two states that finalized the border between them).

Comment: Couldn't you intersect the river with the polygon(s) representing California? I think this is a GIS thing, so you may ask there.

Comment: @BarryCarter: That's easy for you to say. "Intersperse the river with pollywogs"?!?

Comment: @njuffa: Thanks for looking; this info is apparently more arcane than I would have expected.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem a quick search finds a good list :-/  There's probably one out there somewhere, it's just a matter of someone happening to know it/dig it up.  As Barry mentions, there are geographic computer programs that can calculate such things, and the river shapes are out there... but it'd take some definite effort and learning to accomplish if you're unfamiliar :-/